# Sci-fi book about a guy leaving a dying Earth on a colony ship with his daughter in stasis; ship crash lands on a planet with aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

The book starts on slowly dying Earth.  A guy gets last minute selection on a colony ship as electrical person, daughter is already on board in stasis.

The ship crashes on a planet with a few people awake and the rest still in stasis or dead, I can't remember which.

Then there were levels to the planet with different aliens on each one, it might have been a broken weather machine or something.

I can't remember much else.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you read this book, and roughly when do you think it was published?

Comment: Found the book at work at least ten years ago.  It was old then and the cover was missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *Helix* (2007) by Eric Brown.

The ship has crashed on part of the 'Helix', a series of inhabited planets arranged in a helical pattern, four turns 'below' and four turns 'above' the star.

from the book's description:

> they crashland on what they think is a desolate, ice-bound planet.
> Daylight brings the discovery that the planet is one of thousands
> arranged in a vast spiral wound about a central sun. They set off to
> discover a more habitable, Earth-like world

This is what the cover looks like:

[image: Cover of "Helix" by Eric Brown; a caption reads "Eric Brown is the name to watch in SF - Peter F Hamilton". The cover shows a burning, disintegrating ship plunging towards the lower right against a cloudscape. The rear of the ship is entirely engulfed and major chunks are breaking off; the ship trails black smoke. The fore part of the ship, widening slightly in a hammer-head like shape with an antenna-like prow, is still intact. At the very bottom of the cover are what appear to be snow-covered mountain tops, and part of four coils of the titular Helix are visible through the clouds.]